# CMake and dependencies

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies

I have the following directory structure and library dependencies:

```
./lib-a
./lib-b (depending on lib-a)
```

Each directory contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file for generating its own library.
I am using an out-of-source building policy.

In order to say that lib-b depends on lib-a, I have put the command `add_subdirectory(../lib-a lib-a)` in `./lib-b/CMakeLists.txt`, according to what is taught by the [official CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/). This way I obtain that a subdirectory `lib-a` is created in `./lib-b/build dir`.

This is not the behaviour I desire. What I would like to obtain is CMake making reference to lib-a in generating lib-b and, if lib-a has not been already generated, CMake should generate it inside ./lib-a/build by using the CMakeLists.txt of lib-a (in a behaviour similar to the one of the make tool when dealing with dependencies).

I would also like to add that I am not using a root CMakeLists.txt in my example, but what I would like to have is the lib-b/CMakeLists.txt declaring the dependency on lib-a, thus making lib-a to be compiled, if not already, by using its own lib-a/CMakeLists.txt.

Here is the dirs structure and their contents:

```
lib-a/
    CMakeLists.txt (for compiling lib-a)
    src/
        test.cpp
    include/
        test.hpp

lib-b/
   main.cpp
   CMakeLists.txt (for compiling lib-b; here is the point where I would like to make reference to lib-a, that I need for the generation of lib-b)
```

`lib-b/main.cpp` contains also an include of `test.hpp` of `lib-a`, because it is using a function of lib-a. This should be taken into consideration in the specification of `lib-b/CMakeLists.txt`.

What should the content of the two `lib-a/CMakeLists.txt` and `lib-b/CMakeLists.txt` files be?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the tutorial. The thing that links the libraries together is `target_link_library(lib_b lib_a)`. If the name of the dependency is a library that is part of the build, CMake will magically make the dependencies work. It has nothing to do with subdirectories. In fact, if I have the following directory structure:

```
./
./a.hpp
./a.cpp
./b.hpp
./b.cpp
./CMakeLists.txt
```

The following will set the dependencies just fine:

```
PROJECT(lib_a)
ADD_LIBRARY(lib_a a.hpp a.cpp)
PROJECT(lib_b)
ADD_LIBRARY(lib_b b.hpp b.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_b lib_a)
```

This will work across subdirectory projects as well:

```
 ./
 ./CMakeLists.txt
 ./lib_a/CMakeLists.txt
 ./lib_a/a.hpp
 ./lib_a/a.cpp
 ./lib_b/CMakeLists.txt
 ./lib_b/b.hpp
 ./lib_b/b.cpp
```

And the list files:

```
 # ./CMakeLists.txt
 CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
 ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib_a)
 ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib_b)

 # ./lib_a/CMakeLists.txt
 CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
 PROJECT(lib_a)
 ADD_LIBRARY(lib_a a.hpp a.cpp)

 # ./lib_b/CMakeLists.txt
 CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
 PROJECT(lib_b)
 INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${lib_a_SOURCE_DIR})
 ADD_LIBRARY(lib_b b.hpp b.cpp)
 TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_b lib_a)
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer and for the suggestion of using target_link_libraries, but the example you provided does not fit my needs. Indeed, you have all .cpp and .h files in the same dir, and you are writing the deps in a single CMakeLists.txt in the root dir. On my side, instead, I have two dirs each with its own CMakeLists.txt, as explained in the original post. Could you please explain me better how your proposed solution and usage of target_link_libraries can adapt to my case, by please specifying the contents of both lib-a/CMakeLists.txt and lib-b/CMakeLists.txt of my case?

Comment: @davide It works just fine across subdir projects as well. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: Tnx, and what about the include files of lib_a? Should I explicity inclute in lib_b/CMakeLists.txt the target_include_directories command pointing to the lib_a include files directory?

Comment: I've added the naive way. In general, you can get the source directory for a project FOO with `${FOO_SOURCE_DIR}`. There are better ways to do this that isolate just the public headers in the search path for b.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was my comment not clear. What I meant is: do I need to specify explicity in lib_b/CMakeLists.txt the reference to the includes of lib_a, or given that the two libraries are indicated as related (dependency of lib_b to lib_a) the lib_b/CMakeLists.txt automatically makes reference to the includes of lib_a (include dir of lib_a is indicated in the lib_a/CMakeLists.txt...) ?

Comment: @davide lib_b will not automatically have the includes (.h) of lib_a. This is a feature, because you'll often want to hide 3rd party libraries such as boost in the implementation and expose a unified library, and that you usually only want to link against a subset of all includes ("public" header files).